# how to implement source filter property page?

Tags: directshow

I have followed the instructions at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375010%28v=vs.85%29.aspx to create a property page for my CSourceStream based stream.

When testing with amcap I can see that amcap now shows the menu item to show the capture pin properties (ISpecifyPropertyPages::GetPages is queried). The problem is that when amcap calls OleCreatePropertyFrame it returns with E_FAIL and I am not sure why, it does not seem to even get to the stage of quering my dll for the factory method to instantiate the CBasePropertyPage based property class.

Comment: Too little information. `Ezrgb24` sample from Windows SDK features a working property page. As a guess, you forgot a `CFactoryTemplate` for the property page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my DllRegisterServer only registered my filter.

I can use AMovieDllRegisterServer2 to register all components in g_Templates but that function does not register source filters properly so for the moment I am just calling AMovieDllRegisterServer2 and then re-registering my filter with source filter specific code.